# Create clear plane that will prevent render trough

Tags: unity-game-engine

in my unity game i want to create a clear plane at the floor height andd i want it to hide whats under (not to render trough).

[image]

whats happening is that i got 2 doors placed on the ground and beneath i got a tunnel that i dont want to be seen until the doors are opened.
the plane should be place under the 2 doors that open and as long as the camera is above the doors this plane will prevent from the lower part to be rendered.

how can i do it?

Comment: What exactly is "clear plane"? Is it on your image or is that a door?

Comment: i want it to be just below the 2 square doors (one is selected) and it should be big enough to prevent from the camera to see it but at the same time to be transparent.
i heard the term "mask" related to this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Shader "Cover" {
Properties {
}

SubShader {
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "LightMode"="ForwardBase" "Queue"="Geometry-1" }
    LOD 100
    ColorMask 0

    CGINCLUDE
    #include "UnityCG.cginc"

    struct v2f {
        float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
        float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
    };

    v2f vert (appdata_full v)
    {
        v2f o;
        o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
        o.uv = v.texcoord;      
        return o;
    }
    ENDCG

    Pass {
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest       
        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR
        {
            return fixed4(1,1,1,0);
        }
        ENDCG 
    }
}

Fallback "Diffuse"
}
```